Подключение к удаленной базе данных MySQL в MySQL Workbench и ASP.NET Core
У меня есть база данных в monsterasp.net. Я пытаюсь подключиться к ней в visual Studio в моем проекте asp net core:
    "ConnectionStrings": { "DefaultConnection": "Server=db9921.public.databaseasp.net;Database=db9921;Uid=db9921;Pwd=3Kz@Dw-7j%4A; Connect Timeout=60;" },

но EF выдает ошибку:
The exception 'Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.' was thrown while attempting to find 'DbContext' types. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728 

Я также пытаюсь подключиться через MySQL Workbench, где также возникает ошибка. Кто-нибудь знает, в чем может быть проблема? Я включил базу данных на сервере, строки подключения указаны правильно...




у меня получилось соединиться с вашими учетными данными с помощью DBeaver. Попробуйте указать в Default schema db9921

Ну и не забудьте поменять пароль!

Попробовал, ошибка все равно та же(

Так ошибка, которую выдаёт вас EF связанна с неправильной конфигурацией контекста/сущностей/конфигураций, а не с подключением к БД

я попробовал сперва подключиться в MySQL Workbench, а также в DBeaver, и происходит ошибка

telnet db9921.public.databaseasp.net 3306 что-нибудь показывает типа такого: Trying 144.76.227.84... Connected to db9921.public.databaseasp.net. Escape character is '^]'. ] 5.5.5-10.11.9-MariaDB-log0▒@giZgs03▒▒-MjM$jiP3Px-qmysql_native_password ?

Хм, интересно. А какие у вас версии MySql Server и MySql Workbench? А то вот: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/313376

У меня установлен MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE

@AlexanderSt, ничего такого не показывает

@vover Ну вот там по ссылке написано, что если версия MySql Server при этом старая, то Workbench может показывать совсем не то сообщение об ошибке, которая на самом деле.

@CrazyElf, 5.5.5-10.11.9-MariaDB что это за версия - я не очень понял, какие цифры к чему, но бобром у меня подключается, а у вопрошающего- нет. Отсюда можно сделать вывод, что проблемы в настройках компа, возможно фаервола/брандмауэра. Да там может быть куча проблем - битый кэш днс, например. Хотя сейчас telnet стал сразу отваливаться...

В общем, создал новую базу данных и со второй попытки всё заработало... Не знаю что это такое было)
Всем спасибо, кто попытался помочь!
